Creating a Measure for Cumulative Sum with Specific Conditions in Power BI
I need to create a measure to calculate cumulative sum based on another measures.
Here are the conditions:

There are two measures used in this calculation.
One measure provides decimal values, which is used to calculate the cumulative sum as they are unique. The other measure provides rounded-off numbers, which is needed for determining the first value to include.
To achieve the cumulative sum, I need to only add the smallest value among the same rounded-off values.


Currently I've created a measure based on the decimal measure only, like this:
VAR CurrentRowValue = [Measure Value]
VAR c = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Fact_Table[Sum Column]),
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE (
            Fact,
            "PT", [Final_Price_Index],
            "ROUNDEDPT", [Measure Value (Rounded Off)]
        ),
        [PT] <= CurrentRowValue
    )
)
RETURN c

How can I add a condition based on the Rounded off measure? Or is there any other better way to do this?

Can you share the DAX of the measures you already created?

I'm not sure I'm understanding. Seems like all you need to do is change [Measure Value (Rounded Off])] to MIN([Measure Value (Rounded Off)],[Measure Value]) if you want one or the other?

The requirement is to calculate the cumulative sum of a column based on a measure. However, when two measures have the same value, I'm supposed to use the minimum value of the column.

Previously, I relied on one measure, "Measure Value (Rounded Off)" to compute the cumulative sum. However, due to the presence of repetitions, the values were being aggregated. Hence, I introduced another measure, "Measure Value" which is "Measure Value (Rounded Off)" without rounding off

@AmiraBedhiafi, I've already shared the measure to calculate the cumulative sum (the result is in the E column of the shared snapshot). However, I need the values for the F column.

Can you share Measure Value and Measure Value (Rounded Off) ? help us to help you

Sure @AmiraBedhiafi .  Measure Value is: SUM(tableName[columnName]) while in Measure Value (Rounded off) I'm also using the ROUND function ROUND(SUM(tableName[columnName]) , 0)

Column Name here is A, B , C.... ? How are you doing this SUM(tableName[columnName]) ?

The image displayed above represents my expected outcome. I sincerely appreciate your efforts to assist me. But I'm not sure how my measure to calculate the Measure Value will impact the desired outcome. If possible, could you please provide an explanation? Perhaps this will lead me to find a better approach. Thanks!

The column name in your screenshot contains letters, and you are doing SUM(tableName[columnName]) how comes you are summing letters?
I am trying to understand what you provided so I can replicate it ?
